# How to change background colour dynamically using Css

Tags: javascript, css, model-view-controller, onclick, visual-studio-2017

I've set up a method which when a button is clicked changes it's background colour and resets the colour of the other three buttons. The method for button1 looks like this

```
<script>
    function changeBttn1() {
        document.getElementById("bttn1").style.backgroundColor = '#add8e6';
        document.getElementById("bttn2").style.backgroundColor = '#D3D3D3';
        document.getElementById("bttn3").style.backgroundColor = '#D3D3D3';
        document.getElementById("bttn4").style.backgroundColor = '#D3D3D3';
    }...
```

Also I want to be able to make the Div that applies to each button appear and the others hidden with the same button press. The Div uses Class=Collapse which corresponds to Display:None in Bootstrap.css but I want to change it to run from the same method as the buttons. How can I do both events using Css?

Comment: please share the html and a demo if possible

Comment: Just do both lines of code in this same function. Also if you only ever show one div, you don't ever need to change color, keep them all at `#add8e6` and just hide the ones you dont need and show only the one you do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do it like this very simple and easy

```js
$('.my-btn').on('click',function(){
  var colorval=$(this).attr('color');
  $('.my-btn').css('background-color', 'grey');
  $(this).css('background-color', colorval);
});
```

```css
button{
background-color:grey;
padding:10px;
border:1px solid #000000;
color:#ffffff;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button-wrapper">
  <button class="my-btn" color="red">Red</button>
  <button class="my-btn" color="green">Green</button>
  <button class="my-btn" color="purple">Purple</button>
</div>
```